# No logro cambiar de tipo de columna de object a float64, creo estar utilizando bien el codigo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
def extraer_altura(raw_data): 
    raw_data["Altura"].fillna("0000", inplace=True)
    raw_data["Altura"]=raw_data["Altura"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(",",".").replace("'",".").replace("\u200b",""))
    raw_data["Altura"]=raw_data["Altura"].apply(lambda x: x.replace ("[1]","0").replace("'","."))
    raw_data["Altura"]=raw_data["Altura"].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
    raw_data["Altura"]=raw_data["Altura"].apply(lambda x: float(x[0:4]))
    
    assert(isinstance(raw_data, pd.DataFrame))
    return raw_data
```

Comment: Hola! por qué afirmas que no logras hacerlo? que problema tienes? Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta para añadir toda la info relevante

Answer (score 0):

Cuando `Pandas` encuentra distintos tipos de datos o no sabe inferir el tipo de dato que se encuentra en una columna, utiliza `Object`.

Para cambiar de tipo de dato una columna, tienes que utilizar el método `.astype()`. Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
raw_data["Altura"] = raw_data["Altura"].astype(float)
```

Puedo crear un DataFrame de ejemplo para demostrarlo:

```
import pandas as pd

df_ventas = pd.DataFrame({"producto":["zapato", "camisa", "abrigo"],
              "ventas":[5,7,1]})


print("El tipo de dato antes es: ", df_ventas.ventas.dtype)
df_ventas.ventas = df_ventas.ventas.astype(float)
print("El tipo de dato después es: ", df_ventas.ventas.dtype)
```

**Salida:**

```
El tipo de dato antes es:  int64
El tipo de dato después es:  float64
```